# El Capitan 10.11 pod setup endup with 56 SSLRead() return error -36

Tags: ios, curl, cocoapods

I'm trying to install `Cocoapods`. I have updated gem(2.5.1) and ruby(2.3.0).
The command starts ok, but when it's almost finishing, it ends up with an error as shown below. I've retried many times.

[image]

Comment: Did you try `sudo gem install cocoapods` in terminal?

Comment: of cource I did,but it still this way

Comment: Then try uninstalling the gem and reinstalling using terminal

Comment: problem solved, turn out to be the vpn problems